# Log analytics query for Scale Set

Tags: azure-log-analytics

How do I write Log analytics query for Scale Sets. As the scale set VMs scale up and scale down how do i write our query handle that. I need to get available memory on all the instances.

Answer (score 0):

I never enabled Log Analytics for VM scale sets but AFAIK the VM name's of VM scale sets are based on VM scale set naming convention i.e., lets say VM scale set name is 'VMSSName' then the names of instances (VM's) that are part of that particular VM scale set would be something like 'VMSSName_0', 'VMSSName_1', etc. So we may have the query to get available memory on all the instances (VM's) that are part of a VM scale set named 'VMSSName' would be something like shown below. Hope this helps!

```
Perf
| where ( ObjectName == "Memory" )
| where ( CounterName == "Available MBytes" or CounterName == "Available MBytes Memory" )
| where ( Computer startswith "VMSSName_" )
| summarize AggregatedValue= avg(CounterValue) by Computer, bin(TimeGenerated, 30s)
```

Comment: Thanks for the query you had mentioned you never enable Log Analytics for VM scaleset want other alternative do you use to monitor the memory of Log Analytics?